# Showing Error Messages Simultaneously in Radio Button Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form with radio buttons. There are three 'groups' of radio buttons (`opt-out1`, `opt-out2`, `opt-out3`) - each group needs to have a radio button selected before the form can submit. I wrote a function to validate that at least one radio button in each group is selected. If there is not one selected, an error message appears.

The issue is that the error messages appear one after the other instead of all at once. For example, if a button is selected for group 1 and not groups 2 & 3, the error message upon submit will only show for group two, then I submit again with a button selected for group two THEN the next error message will appear to select for group 3.

How can I rewrite my javascript function so that if there is more than one error message (meaning two or more groups do not have a button selected) that the error messages show at the same time instead of one by one?

I tried to break the function into three functions and call each function upon submit but in that case the error messages showed simultaneously but disappeared in a split second after the form processed (and it should not process if there is a group unselected).

Any input is greatly appreciated.

HTML FORM:

```
<div id="opt-out-form">
   <form name="frmSubscription" method="get" action="" onSubmit="return validate();">

        <input type="radio" name="opt-out1" value="test-1"  id="1">Test-1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out1" value="test-2"  id="2">Test-2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out1" value="test-3"  id="3">Test-3<br><br><br>
        <div id="message1"></div>


        <input type="radio" name="opt-out2" value="test-4"  id="4">Test-4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out2" value="test-5"  id="5">Test-5<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out2" value="test-6"  id="6">Test-6<br><br><br>
        <div id="message2"></div>


        <input type="radio" name="opt-out3" value="test-7"  id="7">Test-7<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out3" value="test-8"  id="8">Test-8<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out3" value="test-9"  id="9">Test-9<br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt-out3" value="test-10"  id="10">Other: <input type="text" name="other_reason" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<br><br><br>
        <div id="message3"></div>

      <input type="submit" id="opt-out-button" value="Submit">

    </form>
  </div>  
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function validate() {

  var a1 = document.getElementById('1');
  var a2 = document.getElementById('2');
  var a3 = document.getElementById('3');

  var b1 = document.getElementById('4');
  var b2 = document.getElementById('5');
  var b3 = document.getElementById('6');

  var c1 = document.getElementById('7');
  var c2 = document.getElementById('8');
  var c3 = document.getElementById('9');
  var c4 = document.getElementById('10');

  if ( (a1.checked == false ) && (a2.checked == false ) && (a3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 1";
    return false;
  }

  else if ( (b1.checked == false ) && (b2.checked == false ) && (b3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 2";
    return false;
  }

  else if ( (c1.checked == false ) && (c2.checked == false ) && (c3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message3").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 3";
    return false;
  }

  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an `if` block like that only allows one condition to be true.  Break them apart and use a variable to determine the overall outcome of your function.

```
function validate() {

  var a1 = document.getElementById('1');
  var a2 = document.getElementById('2');
  var a3 = document.getElementById('3');

  var b1 = document.getElementById('4');
  var b2 = document.getElementById('5');
  var b3 = document.getElementById('6');

  var c1 = document.getElementById('7');
  var c2 = document.getElementById('8');
  var c3 = document.getElementById('9');
  var c4 = document.getElementById('10');

  var flag = true;

  if ((a1.checked == false ) && (a2.checked == false ) && (a3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 1";
    flag = false;
  }

  if ((b1.checked == false ) && (b2.checked == false ) && (b3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 2";
    flag = false;
  }

  if ((c1.checked == false ) && (c2.checked == false ) && (c3.checked == false )) {
    document.getElementById("message3").innerHTML = "SELECT GROUP 3";
    flag = false;
  }

  return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in showing two or more error messages at the same time. But now another issue arises where the form won't for process after I select the buttons after getting an error message. Maybe the function is still returning false after the error messages show up and the buttons are all selected?

Comment: You `action` attribute is empty. Should it be?